# Error: Setting an array element with a sequence with keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN and have been getting this error when trying to perform:

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils
trainY=utils.to_categorical(trainY)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My trainY are actually labels, and it looks like this:

```
labels
array([list(['noise']), list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']), list(['noise']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']), list(['noise']),
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([list(['noise']), list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']), list(['noise']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise']), list(['noise', 'point_source']),
       list(['noise', 'point_source']), list(['noise']), list(['noise'])])
```

That was what you had. Now you need to do this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

as_list = [list(i) for i in labels]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
ohe = mlb.fit_transform(as_list) # you might need to add .astype(float)
```

This is what you'll end up with:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1], ...
```

Comment: Hey Nicolas, thank you for your help! Now, when I try to do what you did I get a new error when setting my trainX and trainY split:
`(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(signals, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42) 
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 154]`
Does this mean they are not equal length now? Any tips on how to fix that? I am trying to d make a multi-label classifier, really appreciate your help! @NicolasGervais

Comment: Maybe remove the parentheses? Or do the train test split before using to_categorical? I'm unable to help you further. What's the error

Comment: hm even when I do to_categorical after the train/test split I now have a trainY of shape `(124, 2)` and before was `(80, )' ,  just as the trainX. I also removed the parenthesis. Hm strange, the error is:
`Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 80 input samples and 124 target samples.`  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: So this is supposed to be the target for one observation or two? `list(['noise', 'point_source'])`

Comment: So this is for one observation that contains both noise and point_source, and I want to label each. @NicolasGervais

Comment: So one observation of signal has both noise and point_source, and some of them just have noise. So each list represents labels that one observed signal has (hope it's clear)

Comment: I understand. I'll get back to you within an hour

Comment: See my updated answer. It doesn't seem possible to use targets with different length with `to_categorical()`, and I am not able to use `keras` at the moment. I hope this solution is ok for you

Comment: thank you very much Nicolas, I've seen MultiLabelBinarizer and have been trying to set that but you just helped me a lot! Big thanks! One more small question, can I use the same method even if I have more labels? The number shouldn't matter, right? @NicolasGervais